# Lua: how do I return the module itself when requiring a module?

Tags: class, module, lua, constructor

I want to create a module something like this

myclass.lua

```
local myclass = {
  print = function()
`    print(myclass.name)
  end,
  setname = function(name)
    myclass.name = name
  end
}

-- Constructor
local function new(name)
  local o = {name = ""}
  setmetatable(o, myclass)
  return o
end

return _this_module__  <<== How can I do this?:
```

In order to use this module like this:

```
myclasscode = require("myclass")

local object1 = myclasscode.new("hello")
local object2 = myclasscode.new("goodbye")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define it on your own. The "module" here, or rather the thing that `require` returns is whatever is returned by the required file. For instance:

one.lua:

```
return 1
```

and then:

```
print(require("one")) --> 1
```

In the usual case you want to provide a set of functions to the user. Using tables is the most straight-forward choice to do it:

myclass.lua:

```
local function new(name)
  -- constructor code here
end

return {
  new=new,
  -- anything else that the module should provide
}
```

`require` will return the table with the `'new'` member that holds the constructor function. User then can use it like this:

```
local myclass = require("myclass")
local instance = myclass.new("hey")
```

Because it's just a regular value you can do whatever you want with it. You can get quite close to what you wanted with:

```
local _this_module_ = {}

function _this_module_.new(name)
  -- constructor code here
end

return _this_module_
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping maybe if you return nothing from a module, it returns the module as if it were a function, like the dofile function would do with a file, something like that or loadstring. But what you've given me is just as good.

Comment: @WaltHoward If you skip caching (preload, loaded) and path resolution, require can be explained as `loadfile("file.lua")("file", "file.lua")`. The last variant is probably the closest thing to what you want to have.